# Features that cannot be exported to other 3D software

Tags: export

I heard that crease is unable to export to other softwares. What features can't be exported related to modeling and animating?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures/57541